# Ordnance Survey MasterMap Symbols not appearing properly styled on QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, ordnance-survey, os-mastermap

Using plugin OS Translator II on the Exeter sample database.
Ticked the boxes "Add OS Styling Fields" and "Apply Default OS style"

Connected to PostGIS database. All worked apart from the Symbols for CartographicSymbol and TopographicPoint. The symbols are random letters and shapes. And huge. Big Magenta N and Grey question marks for NonConiferenceTrees etc.

I've got the osmmsymbol folder in the appropriate QGIS folder. Changed Settings-Options-SVG Paths to C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/svg/ in addition to the default C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./svg/ (What is that weird dot for??).

I can manually change the symbols. Via LayerProperties-Symbology and selected one of the 6 Legends. A double click to show Symbol Selector and then click on Font Marker and change to SVG marker. But thereafter it is hunt the symbol. And when applied the size is wrong. After fiddling I can fix that too.

I believe the symbols should automagically appear without manual intervention.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the symbol are random letters and/or shape it's because those symbols are not intended to be svg but font and you don't have the right font installed (so a fallback font with different symbol are used).

You should try to find the right font and install it on your system (the Github of ordnance survey provide font file with their stylesheet, just find the one you need https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey), the svg you have are a way to overcome the missing font (as you did) but you loose the automated part of the process

Comment: Great stuff J.R. - I'd "installed" the TTF but it had somehow associated itself with QGIS. So the double click opened QGIS which I'd assumed was to install the TTF into QGIS directly. Associated it manually with Windows Font Viewer and installed from there.